# Encoding a QString in JSON

Tags: qt, qt5, qwebelement

I'm trying to encode a QString into a JSON string, so that I can inject it safely via `QWebFrame::evaluateJavaScript(QString("o.text = %1;").arg(???))`.

For example, in php using the function json_encode

```
echo json_encode('HELLO "me"');
```

The output would be

> "HELLO \"me\""

This is the internal representation of the string, within the Json object.

In the same way, using Qt, how can I retrieve the internal representation of a string, as it would be encoded as a value, within a Json formatted string?

Comment: Use Qt's QJson classes, such as [QJsonDocument](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html), [QJsonObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html) etc

Comment: How can I use QJSonDocument to encode a single QString?
It accepts either a QJsonArray or a QJsonObject, but not a QJsonValue...

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really not that difficult. Start by building up the structure with QJsonObjects

```
QJsonObject obj;
obj.insert("tag1", QString("Some text"));
```

Then use QDocument to get a string in Json format

```
QJsonDocument doc(obj);
QByteArray data = doc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact);

QString jsonString(data);
```

This will produce a string, in the form of: -

> { "tag1" : "Some Text" }

Separate items into a list, splitting on ':'

```
QStringList items = jsonString.split(':', QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

There should be 2 items in the list, the second being the value section of the Json string

> "Some Test"}

Remove the final '}'

QString value = items[1].remove('}');

Of-course, you will need to do error checking and be aware that if you have a ':' or '}' in the original string, then you'll need to check for them first.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted my request. :)
I need a string encoded in JSON to be able to inject it in a string safely.
Try running this code `echo json_encode('HELLO "me"');` here: http://phptester.net/

Comment: Tried it at that site and it didn't work - the result is blank.

Comment: It works with [this interpreter](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php_terminal_online.php) and I see what you mean. Your question is really badly worded!

Comment: Uh... Sorry for my English... :P

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
I changed, though, the `remove('}')` call to this `.remove(QRegularExpression("\\}$"));`

Answer (score 2):

Original answer doesn't handle `:` and `}` inside of string correctly. A similar approach using array which requires only stripping `[]`:

```
QString encodeJsonStringLiteral(const QString &value)
{
    return QString(
                QJsonDocument(
                    QJsonArray() << value
                ).toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact)
           ).mid(1).chopped(1);
}
```

`ab"c'd` becomes `"ab\"c'd"`

Or, if you don't need double quotes around the string, replace with `.mid(2).chopped(2)`